# Pagination in php using div and bootstrap

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I'm trying to implement a simple pagination using `PHP` and `Twitter Bootstrap` but got stuck.

Everything seems to work fine the only problem is my div's are floating all around leaving some empty spaces in the page like in this picture:

[image: screenshot]

Below is my code:

```
<?php foreach($tester as $data): ?>
<div class="col-sm-2">
  <img src="" width="150" height="150"/>
  <br>
  <span><?php echo $data['Description'];?></span><br>
  <span><?php echo $data['Unit_Price'];?></span><br>
  <span>In Stock:<?php echo $data['Qty'];?></span><br>
  <span>Arriving Soon:<?php echo $data['In_Transit'];?></span><br>
  <span>Show All Products In:<?php echo $data['P_Class_Name'];?></span>
  </div>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: Are you wrapping it in a `.row`?

Answer (score 0):

Put `class="clearfix"` div after each 6 elements to create non float sensitive line break

```
<?php $i=0; foreach($tester as $data): $i++; ?>
<div class="col-sm-2">
  <img src="" width="150" height="150"/>
  <br>
  <span><?php echo $data['Description'];?></span><br>
  <span><?php echo $data['Unit_Price'];?></span><br>
  <span>In Stock:<?php echo $data['Qty'];?></span><br>
  <span>Arriving Soon:<?php echo $data['In_Transit'];?></span><br>
  <span>Show All Products In:<?php echo $data['P_Class_Name'];?></span>
  </div>
  <?php if ($i % 6 == 0) { ?><div class="clearfix"><?php } ?>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

However, this solution shouldn't be used if you need a different number of elements to displayed per row for a different viewpoint size.